# Return farthest deviation from zero with its sign? Excel

Tags: excel

I have a set of numbers that fluctuate say, +/- 0.020 about zero, and I am trying to find the maximum deviation from zero.  The problem is, if the numbers are all negative (that is only one case, it could be that the maximum positive number is like 0.005 and the maximum negative number is -0.020, and I need to return -0.020 in this case), I am not finding the maximum deviation from zero when using the `MAX(myrange)` function.  I thought about using `MAX(ABS(myrange))`, but that won't work either as it would return 0.020 instead of -0.020 (sign matters in this case).  What is a function that will get Excel to return the correct value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the absolute value of the maximum is greater than the absolue value of the minimum, then the farthest deviation is the maximum.  Else it is the minimum.  Excel provides an `IF` function that should help you here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
=SMALL(IF(MAX(ABS(A1:A5))=ABS(A1:A5),A1:A5),1)
```

This is an *array formula*, so type the formula then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Curly brackets will automatically appear at the start and end of the formula.

Note, if you have both values, `-0.020` and `0.020` (with max deviation), formula above returns `-0.020`. If you want to returns `0.020`, change `SMALL` to `LARGE`

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up using was an `IF` statement.  I am having VBA code populate the formula.  It is something like `IF(MIN(dummyrange)>MAX(dummyrange),MIN(dummyrange),MAX(dummyrange))`.  If the values are exactly equal, it doesn't matter which value it returns, because I am just looking for max deviation, and the plot will probably give some insight into this case.  Also, the likelihood of two outputs being exactly 100% the same is slim to none.  I don't know the actual possibility, but the machine measures to 7 decimal places.

Comment: Comment from an anonymous edit suggestion: "I added the ABS to the equation. Otherwise the IF statement will always be false": `IF(ABS(MIN(dummyrange))>MAX(dummyrange),MIN(dummyrange),MAX(dummyrange))`